# MS Dynamics 365 for Operations source not found while debugging

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-ax7

In **MS Dynamics 365 for Operations (AX7)**, I'm trying to debug a form method. 
I can set breakpoints. I can start debugging and it stops at breakpoint as it should. But then, when I click <kbd>F11</kbd>, an error is shown:

> "Source not found"

There is no such file with .*xpp* extension found, so debugging is not working.

How to find required *.xpp* source file? How to solve this issue? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Which form's method you are not able to step in?

Comment: It doesn't meter, I cannot step in any method.

Comment: Indeed it matters. The more details you provide about your issue, the easier is for people to help you

Comment: I mean that it happens with all methods I try to step in. The only way how it is working right now, if go till this source error and them open method manually. I've checked it with several methods and in two different environments and I still have the same problem. Any ideas how to fix it? I cannot find anything about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you do not have the setting checked to load only symbols in your solution.

To turn off this setting, go to Tools -> Options -> Find the "Dynamics 365" node and expand it -> Debugging -> **Uncheck** "Load symbols only for itmes in the solution"

[image]

I have run into this occasionally during development even after unchecking this box, and I usually have to reboot my dev VM for it to figure itself out. I think there are some other reasons it can't find the symbols but I haven't investigated further. Also, this will impact performance; the increased amount of symbols loaded will slow the start of the debugger.

**Edit** I ran into this again even with the box unchecked. One way I got around it (even though this is a workaround, not a real fix) is to open the methods that it is looking for and restarting debugging. If the method/class/form whatever code is loaded in the Visual Studio editor, it will "find" it. Not a pretty solution, but at least you can step through the code...

**Edit 2** As per Vadim's comment: "it's not necessary to restart debugging. When the code has been loaded in the Visual Studio the way you described, just click the previous line in the call stack to jump to the place where the missing file was called from. After that click the last line of the stack and you will come to the current statement."

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to restart debugging. When the code has been loaded in the Visual Studio the way you described, just click the previous line in the call stack to jump to the place where the missing file was called from. After that click the last line of the stack and you will come to the current statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue in my environment by creating a solution and project and having the project in my extension model. I did not have to add the code I was debugging to the project.